# insert after last element using jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST" style="margin-top: 20px; ">
        <div class="row btts-form-group clearfix">
    <div style="width: 20%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
        Image : <input type="file" name="image[]">
    </div>  
    <div style="width: 27%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
        Title : <input type="text" name="title[]">
    </div>

    <div style="width: 22%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
        More Info : <input type="text" name="more_info[]">
    </div>

    <div style="width: 22%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
        Button : <input placeholder="Put the url.." type="text" name="button_link[]">
    </div>
    <div style="width: 5%; float: left; ">
        <input type="button" class="button button-primary add_more" value="+">
    </div>
</div>


        <input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save Change" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    </form>
```

Here is my simple jquery code to append a row of a form:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('body').on('click', '.add_more', function(e){


            $.ajax({
                url : absbBtToS.ajax_url,
                type : 'get',
                data : {
                    action : 'new_slider_html',
                    security : absbBtToS.check_nonce

                },
                success : function( response ) {

                    $('.btts-form-group:last').after(response);
                    //console.log(response);
                    //jQuery('.rml_contents').html(response);
                },
                error : function(error){
                   console.log(error);
                }
            });

          e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        });
     });
```

Ajax Action :

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_new_slider_html',  'new_slider_html');

function new_slider_html(){
    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'admin/partials/absb_bt_to_s-admin-display.php');

        if( !check_ajax_referer( 'absbBtToS-nonce', 'security' ) ){
            wp_send_json_error('error!');
        }

      show_slider_form_input();
}
```

And   `show_slider_form_input();` definition is as follows which is inside absb_bt_to_s-admin-display.php:

```
function show_slider_form_input(){?>
<div class="row btts-form-group clearfix" >
    <div style="width: 20%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
        Image : <input type="file" name="image[]"  />
    </div>  
    <div style="width: 27%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
        Title : <input type="text" name="title[]" />
    </div>

    <div style="width: 22%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
        More Info : <input type="text" name="more_info[]" />
    </div>

    <div style="width: 22%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
        Button : <input placeholder="Put the url.." type="text" name="button_link[]" />
    </div>
    <div style="width: 5%; float: left; ">
        <input type="button" class="button button-primary add_more"  value="+" />
    </div>
</div>

<?php }
```

But when I click once. Two row added. it seems $('.btts-form-group:last').after(response); is executed two times.  I also added  `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` but no luck. Any idea?

Comment: Sattar Bhuiyah can you able to share your HTML code

Comment: do you have a fiddle or snippet to show your issue?

Comment: can you tell me what is ajax response give you means what value in response variable?

Comment: please create an executable snippet so we can better help you. right now it's a bit impossible to guess... could be the structure of your HTML, could be the ajax response... could be pure magic....

Comment: I update my question and add HTML. @kalaiselvan

Comment: I update my question and add HTML. @Ronen Cypis

Comment: what is in `new_slider_html`

Comment: Update again. Hope now no single point is missed to mention.

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan make sure that yours ajax response

Answer (score 0):

your code is working fine without any problem and make sure that your ajax response, In your case your ajax response is the problem

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.add_more', function(e){
    var arr=['<div class="row btts-form-group clearfix" >','<div style="width: 20%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">','Image : <input type="file" name="image[]"  />','</div>','<div style="width: 27%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">','Title : <input type="text" name="title[]" />','</div>','<div style="width: 22%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">','More Info : <input type="text" name="more_info[]" />','</div>','<div style="width: 22%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">','Button : <input placeholder="Put the url.." type="text" name="button_link[]" />','</div>','<div style="width: 5%; float: left; ">','<input type="button" class="button button-primary add_more"  value="+" />','</div>','</div>'];
    var response=arr.join("");
     $('.btts-form-group:last').after(response);
      /*$.ajax({
        url : absbBtToS.ajax_url,
        type : 'get',
        data : {
          action : 'new_slider_html',
          security : absbBtToS.check_nonce
        },
        success : function( response ) {
          $('.btts-form-group:last').after(response);
          //console.log(response);
          //jQuery('.rml_contents').html(response);
        },
        error : function(error){
                   console.log(error);
        }
      });*/
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST" style="margin-top: 20px; ">
  <div class="row btts-form-group clearfix">
<div style="width: 20%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
  Image : <input type="file" name="image[]">
</div> 
<div style="width: 27%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
  Title : <input type="text" name="title[]">
</div>

<div style="width: 22%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
  More Info : <input type="text" name="more_info[]">
</div>

<div style="width: 22%; float: left; margin-right: 1%;">
  Button : <input placeholder="Put the url.." type="text" name="button_link[]">
</div>
<div style="width: 5%; float: left; ">
  <input type="button" class="button button-primary add_more" value="+">
</div>
</div>   

  <input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save Change" style="margin-top: 20px;">
</form>
```

I hope it will helpful to you